# Google Analytics Ignores a Semicolon Based Query String

Tags: google-analytics

I have my urls in this format: **https://www.example.com/product.xhtml;my-product-name**. However, Google Analytics only captures **https://www.example.com/product.xhtml** and ignores the part after the semi-colon, which is a query string. How do I fix that? There is a bit of information about filters but non seems to address my issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You might use some Javascript in your application to alter the page path reported to Analytics.

Comment: I just decided to change the URL all together, from https://www.example.com/product.xhtml;my-product-name to https://www.example.com/my-product-name.html (had to settle for some urls with xhtml and others with html to overcome some rewrite challenges)